# php script that includes class structure doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a php script running on centos 5.x
When i use a code like

```
$db->connect();
```

php script doesn't work.I use `php myscript.php`
and it does nothing.
..
..
..

```
$db->connect();
echo "Hello world";
```

when i run above script it does nothing.Nothing means the like this;
[root@xxxxxxx update_call_history]# php update_call_history.php  {press enter} 
[root@xxxxxxx update_call_history]#

but if i change the script like this

```
echo "hello world";
```

it works.I think my php doesnt run class structured script,Is there any missing module or what.
Thanks for advance...

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? If there's nothing else then it's quite simple : you get a fatal error because you're trying to call a method on an object that doesn't exist yet ($db). Turn on php error logging in php.ini (setting log_errors & error_log), run your script again and check the log afterwards.

Comment: i included the class file but i didnt wrote above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-mysql module wasn't installed so it couldn't connect to database.

Answer (score 1):

If all the information you've been able to gather is "doesn't work" you need to do two things:

1. Configure your environment to generate and display/log all error messages.
2. Check the return value of the function calls, test whether it was successful and print the exact error message if not.

Comment: is there any possibility for missing php mysql module?

Comment: If your code uses it (your question doesn't even mention MySQL) and it's not available, you should get a *Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_whatever* error message somewhere.

Comment: my problem was missing module which is called php-mysql.In my class i closed the error message for that reason it didn't display.thank for care

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- mysql server is on
- you have turned on error reporting
- you are specifying correct credentials

Comment: mysql server is on,
i used
 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

at the begining of the script.And what do you mean with correct credentials?